# Filtrar array de objetos mediante sus parámetros

Tags: javascript

Me gustaria saber como poder filtrar en un array de objetos, pasandole una cadena

```
const userBiz = users.filter(user => user.website);
console.log(userBiz);
```

Este es el array de objetos del que necesito sacar

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,               
    "website": "hildegard.org",       
  },
  {
    "id": 2,        
    "website": "anastasia.biz"        
  },{
    "id": 3,        
    "website": "adsfasdf.net"        
  }
]
```

Comment: Deberías agregar el array en cuestión

Answer (score 1):

El ejemplo que pones es un ejemplo correcto de como filtrar una lista. En tu caso filtrará por todos los elementos que contengan algún valor en la propiedad `website`

Si quieres filtrar que el contenido de `website` sea uno específico lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
user = [ {"website": "one"}, {"website": "one"}, {"website": "two"}, {"website": "one"} ]

oneUsers = user.filter( user => user.website == "one") // devuelve 3 elementos
twoUsers = user.filter( user => user.website == "two") // devuelve 1 elemento
usersWithE = user.filter( user => user.website.contains("e")) // devuelve 3 elementos
```

Comment: @ManuelJhp el código de esta respuesta es correcto ya lo probaste?

Comment: Lo probé y no me reconoce el contains, me sale un error en la consola, me muestra esto: **Uncaught TypeError: user.website.contains is not a function** incluso copiando el ejemplo con su array

Comment: @ManuelJhp con que navegador? según https://caniuse.com/?search=contains no deberías tener problemas.